# replace global when needle is a variable

Tags: javascript, regex

How can you use the global modifier when the needle to be replaced is a variable?

```
var needle = '/'+key+'/g';
str = str.replace(needle, trans[key]);
```

Comment: try doing ss = trans[key] , str = str.replace(needle,ss); - not sure what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap your needle for this:

```
var needle = new RegExp(key, "g");
```